# Logic to get Date Of Birth From Age expressed in years months and days

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a react component that has a date of birth input and an age input that take input in years, months and days.

So I want to get the Date Of Birth of the person if the age is typed.

For example,
  Age is Years = 24, Months = 1, Days = 15
So the Date of Birth should be 18-04-1993..

Here's what I've done so far.. But the logic is breaking at if (nowDay <= ageDay) block..

```
const now = new Date();
const nowDay = now.getDate();
const nowMonth = now.getMonth() + 1;
const nowYear = now.getFullYear();
const ageYear = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.yearInput).value;
const ageMonth = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.monthInput).value;
const ageDay = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.daysInput).value;
let dobYear = nowYear - ageYear;
let dobMonth = nowMonth - ageMonth;
let dobDay = nowDay - ageDay;
if (dobMonth <= 0) {
  dobYear --;
  dobMonth = (12 + dobMonth);
}
if (ageMonth > 12) {
  dobYear = dobYear + Math.floor(dobMonth / 12);
  console.log('ASIJASOIJAS', dobYear); // eslint-disable-line
  dobMonth = ageMonth % 12;
}
if (nowDay <= ageDay) {
  dobMonth -= Math.floor(ageDay / 30);
  dobDay = ageDay % 30;
  if (dobMonth < 0) {
    dobYear = dobYear - (dobMonth % 12) - 1;
    dobMonth = 12 - (dobMonth % 12);
    dobDay ++;
  }
}
const age = {
  days: ageDay,
  months: ageMonth,
  years: ageYear,
};
const month = dobMonth < 10 ? `0${dobMonth}` : dobMonth;
const day = dobDay < 10 ? `0${dobDay}` : dobDay;
dateOfBirth = `${dobYear}-${month}-${day}`;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look, sometimes people don't like libraries and it's not an answer to your question (hence the comment), but check out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), it's an awesome library that deals with all sorts of time issues, including exactly the one you have now. Highly recommended!

Comment: Agree with Brett East. You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Moment JS is perfect to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: @Brett East.. Thank you for your suggestion.. I'll check it out.. The reason I ignored it was because Momentjs is big library and my small app just needed this calculation to be done.. So including
that whole library for just one small part was unnecessary I felt.. Guess I'm wrong.. 

Comment: MomentJS is a bit like Joda time in Java. It's external, sure, but it makes up for a huge failing in the date libraries of the core language. It's almost irresponsible to rely on the Javascript date libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) as suggested in the comments above, a simple function like this might do the trick. Note that it returns a Date object so you will have to format it into whatever string format you want it in.

```js
const getBirthDateFromAge = (ageYears, ageMonths, ageDays) => {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - ageYears);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - ageMonths);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - ageDays);
  return date;
};

console.log(getBirthDateFromAge(10, 9, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

**In nodejs es6 :**

```js
const leapyear = ( year ) => {
    return year % 100 === 0 ?
        year % 400 ===
        0 : year % 4 === 0;
}

const countDaysByYears = ( year ) => {
    let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    let count = 0;
    while ( year != 0 ) {
        if ( leapyear( currentYear ) ) count++;
        year -= 1;
        currentYear -= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

const getMyDoB = ( years, months, days ) => {
    months = ( months / 12 );
    days = ( ( days + countDaysByYears( years ) ) / 365 );
    var ageInYears = years + months + days;
    var ageInMillis = ageInYears * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Date( Date.now() - ageInMillis );
}

console.log( getMyDoB( 31, 7, 19 ).toDateString() );
console.log( getMyDoB( 25, 0, 24 ).toDateString() );
```